# XMLHttpRequest not showing anything

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am using XMLHttpRequest like this: 
I created one variable uname for storing username and one variable msg for storing messages.

```
 <script>
    function submitChat() {
        if(form1.uname.value == '' || form1.msg.value == ''){
            alert('ALL FIELDS ARE MANDATORY');
            return;
        }
        var uname = form1.uname.value;
        var msg = form1.msg.value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?uname='+uname+'&msg='+msg, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

My form looks like this

```
<form name="form1">
Enter your chat name: <input type="text" name="uname" /> <br />
Your message: <br />
<textarea name="msg"></textarea> <br />
<a href="#" onclick="submitChat()"> Send </a><br/><br/>
<div id="chatlogs">
    LOADING CHAT LOGS PLEASE WAIT...
</div>
```

what I am doing is that, when I am feeding data to the boxes(input and textarea) and then clicking the link(Send), then the chat logs should be displayed in the div section with id chatlogs, but its not happening, I created database like this:

```
 <?php
$uname = $_REQUEST['uname'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'chatbox');

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO logs ('username', 'msg') VALUES ('$uname', '$msg')");
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");

while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>".$extract ['msg'] ." </span><br />";
}
?>
```

and logs look like this

```
    <?php
$con  = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db('chatbox', $con);
$result1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "<span class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br />";
}
?>
```

Right now when I am filling the input and text area and then clicking the send link, nothing is happening. Neither the data is stored in database nor it is being displayed in the div section.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the console for error messages?

Comment: Did you create the database chatbox in localhost as user root and filled the good password in `mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');`

Comment: it says, "document.getElementById(...) is null"

Comment: @Cryptopat, no password and yes I created the database as mentioned

Comment: Your code is using getElementById but the div does not have any id, only a class name. Use `document.getElementByClassName("chatlogs")[0].innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText` instead, or give your div an id `<div id="chatlogs">`

Comment: no no, actually I a was trying with the class name and forgot to change it, in console it shows nothing

Comment: You must provide more details or a demo link

Comment: will this help https://github.com/AdityaKumar774/Chat-Application

Comment: I am asking both the values from the user

Comment: I would be glad to help but setting up a sql database is the worst thing i dislike in the world. This is why many dev use flat files databases, json, xml, csv, sqlite...portability. Probably the code you provide is okay, how can we know.  sql is the worst database for portability

Comment: well, i am not doing some heavy task...just taking data from user, storing it to the database and showing it inside another container(div).